# \dotfill linebreak problem

Tags: xetex

I am generating an address book in XeTeX and found a problem I cannot solve. So an address book is a list of Names, addresses and number split in columns. Ideally, one entry should look like this (underscores represent space):

> Name.........Number
>
> Address______Number2

I had no problem achieving this layout, there is only a small problem when name is to long and splits into more lines, then it should look something like this:

> Long nameeeeeeeeeeee
>
> more name .......Number

or

> Long  nameeeeeeeee
>
> ...............Number

The first one is also not a problem, but second one gives me headaches. It turns out like this:

> Long nameeeeeee
>
> Number

There are no dots...

Here is simplified (but enough to reproduce the problem) version of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[b4paper, left=2cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=4cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Font
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
  % Case 1
  \noindent
  \vbox {\vfil
    \hbox to \columnwidth {
      \parbox{0.97\columnwidth}{
        \scriptsize
        \raggedright{\textbf{Name}}\dotfill~(XX)~XXX~XXX\\
        \emph{Address}\hfill~(XX)~XXX~XXX}
    }
    \vfil
  }

  % Case 2
  \noindent
  \vbox {\vfil
    \hbox to \columnwidth {
      \parbox{0.97\columnwidth}{
        \scriptsize
        \raggedright{\textbf{Name Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum}}\dotfill~(XX)~XXX~XXX\\
        \emph{Address}\hfill~(XX)~XXX~XXX}
    }
    \vfil
  }

  % Case 3
  \noindent
  \vbox {\vfil
    \hbox to \columnwidth {
      \parbox{0.97\columnwidth}{
        \scriptsize
        \raggedright{\textbf{Name Lorem Ipsum Lorem}}\dotfill~(XX)~XXX~XXX\\
        \emph{Address}\hfill~(XX)~XXX~XXX}
    }
    \vfil
  }

\vspace*{\fill}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

(Actually I defined class and each address-book entry is a command.)

So, could you help me diagnose this problem? Why doesn't `\dotfill` push the number to the right in the third case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

leaders are like glue and get discarded at the beginning of a line. So you want something more like `\hspace*` than `\hspace` which puts something invisible at the start of the line to stop it being discarded, replace `\dotfill` by

```
\penalty0\hbox{}\nobreak\dotfill
```

which allows the break before the box, but doesn't allow a break after the box so the leaders are protected by the box and are not discarded.

[image]

Comment: I don't fully understand why, but this works like a charm :) Thnx